# cordova orientationchange event for IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am doing a small cordova application for android and IOS and I am not able to make the "orientationchange" event in IOS.

It is working in Android adding the javascript line:

```
         window.addEventListener('orientationchange',  onOrientationChange, false);
```

But in IOS is not working, I have read that the reason is the UIWebView element does not support events at window level.

Anybody knows how to detect this type of event in a cordova application for IOS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [cordova-plugin-device-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device-orientation)
Check out the docs [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/index.html)

```
var watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(compassSuccess, compassError, [compassOptions]);
```